# Removing a component from a parent array

Tags: reactjs, typescript

The parent component has a button that creates a new child component in the array.
The child component has a button that should remove it from the array. I wrote a function and passed it through a prop, but it doesn't work.

**Parent:**

```
function App() {
  const [cardArray, setCardArray] = useState<ReactElement[]>([]);

  const handleAdd = () => {
    setCardArray((prevArray: ReactElement[]) => [
      ...prevArray,
      <Category
        key={prevArray.length}
        onDelete={() => handleDelete(prevArray.length)}
      />,
    ]);
  };

  const handleDelete = (index: number) => {
    const updatedComponents = [...cardArray];
    updatedComponents.splice(index, 1);
    setCardArray(updatedComponents);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="categories">
        <div className="categories-block">
          <p>Categories</p>
        </div>
        <p className="plus" onClick={handleAdd}>
          +
        </p>
        <p className="plus">-</p>
      </div>
      <div className="subcategories">
        {cardArray.map((component, index) => (
          <Category onDelete={() => handleDelete(cardArray.length)} />
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**Child:**

```
interface IProps {
  onDelete(): void;
}

function Category({ onDelete }: IProps) {

  return (
    <div className="Category">
      <div className="category">
        <div className="category-block">
        </div>
        <div>
          <p className="delete edit-menu-item" onClick={onDelete}>
            X
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I did something similar on a regular JS, but there were problems with TypeScript.

Comment: Is the last item always getting deleted?

Comment: Typo?  Didn't you mean to pass `index` to `handleDelete`?  (It's also not clear why you have an array of *components* in the first place.  You don't use those components, and just render new ones to the length of the array.  The same could be accomplished with just a single numeric value in state to indicate the number of components to render.)

Comment: that's what I was thinking, hence i asked if it's always getting the last one since he's passing in cardArray.length